# Add view to UITableView using insets, does it have any problem?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am adding a view at the bottom of an `UITableView` (or `UICollextionView` ) but not as a cell or footer but just adding it to the table view itself (so, to the `UIScrollView`) and then playing with the `contentInset` of the scroll. The purpose of this is to keep the view at the bottom of the content of the table, instead of at the end of the content. This way, if the content is shorter than table's bounds the view is visible (left image), but if the content is taller the view appears at the end of the content (right image).

[image: footer]

This is an excerpt of the code:

```swift
let yCoord = collectionView.contentSize.height >= view.frame.height - viewHeight
    ? collectionView.contentSize.height
    : view.frame.height - viewHeight

let bottomView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: yCoord, width: collectionView.contentSize.width, height: viewHeight))

collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: viewHeight, right: 0)
collectionView.addSubview(bottomView)
```

I am wondering if this kind of approach could be considered harmful in any way, for instance, problems with AL, rotations, reload of the table... I don't identify any, indeed this is a very similar approach to the pull-to-refresh feature before iOS 6, but I rather be sure about it before pushing it to production.

If this could be considered a problem, which solution do you propose besides adding a new cell?

Comment: How do you calculate the yCoord ? Why not using those computations to decide if the view should be added above our table view or as a tableViewFooterView ? Here, even if the content is shorter than table's bound, the user can scroll the table view a bit (expect if you set alwaysBounceVertical to false, but this is not a native behavior)

Comment: Hi all. I just posted a excerpt of my code but it works. I am not asking for a working solution but a better one. I mean, I think that checking the coordinate of the content offset and so on is more complicated than doing it like that, IMHO. Anyway, I added the full code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want above functionality you have to take tableView and bottom view in scrollView and give dynamic height to tableView based on content using content observer and keep the bottom View at the bottom of the scrollview and give tableView as top to bottom view and give greaterThan or equal as attributed.

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code. Make your ***footer view color clear and put one another view inside your footer view*** with bottom, left, right and height constraint

```
@IBOutlet weak var footerView: UIView!

   //MARK:- View Controller life cycle method
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    yourTableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    yourTableView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize")
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if(keyPath == "contentSize"){
            let contentHeight: CGFloat = yourTableView.contentSize.height
            let tableHeight = yourTableView.frame.size.height

            if contentHeight < tableHeight {
                footerView.frame = CGRect(x: footerView.frame.origin.x, y: footerView.frame.origin.y, width: footerView.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(tableHeight - contentHeight + 44.0))
                // 44.0 is your initial footer height which you put in xib

            } else {
                footerView.frame = CGRect(x: footerView.frame.origin.x, y: footerView.frame.origin.y, width: footerView.frame.size.width, height: 44.0)
                 // 44.0 is your initial footer height which you put in xib
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to create an UIView subclass which wraps the table view and the floating footer view. I avoid to modify view hierarchy of classes entirely managed by the framework and using a subclass it would be easy to use this layout elsewhere. Using the scroll view delegate `scrollViewDidScroll` event, it would update the footer view frame each time the user scrolls. By the way, I would certainly use contraints to place my footer view rather than playing with frames which are subject to change.

**Is there something harmful in your implementation ?**

You didn't mention where you added your code. If it's the viewDidLoad, then you will have trubles if you're using auto layout and the view's frame changes because of a rotation or a trait collection change. Also, if your content is not static, calling reload data will invalidate the content size of the table view which will also create a misplaced footer view.

**Where should we put those lines of code ?**

Should we KVO observe the table view frame and its content to update the footer view's frame each time they change ?

Of course not ! Apple already provided all the events we need. At least, put those lines in `viewDidLayoutLayouts` and make sure to not add your footer view multiple times. `viewDidLayoutLayouts` is called each time the view of the controller is laid out.

Comment: I am adding it when displaying last cell. I've updated the question.